# Nest array of objects by hierarchy level JavaScript/TypeScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object

I have a dataset similar to the one below:

```
dataSet = {rows: [
    {"ID":0, "Value":10, "HIERARCHY_LEVEL":1},
    {"ID":1, "Value":20, "HIERARCHY_LEVEL":2},
    {"ID":2, "Value":55, "HIERARCHY_LEVEL":3},
    {"ID":3, "Value":77, "HIERARCHY_LEVEL":2},
    {"ID":4, "Value":29, "HIERARCHY_LEVEL":3},
    {"ID":5, "Value":44, "HIERARCHY_LEVEL":4},
    {"ID":6, "Value":34, "HIERARCHY_LEVEL":5},
    {"ID":7, "Value":56, "HIERARCHY_LEVEL":4},
    {"ID":8, "Value":23, "HIERARCHY_LEVEL":2},
    {"ID":9, "Value":23, "HIERARCHY_LEVEL":3},
    {"ID":10, "Value":23, "HIERARCHY_LEVEL":1},
    {"ID":11, "Value":23, "HIERARCHY_LEVEL":2},
    {"ID":12, "Value":23, "HIERARCHY_LEVEL":2},
    {"ID":13, "Value":23, "HIERARCHY_LEVEL":3},
]}
```

I would like to re-arrange this dataSet by the hierarchy level, so each level is put into a `children` property array of the previous object like below:

> NOTE: The dataSet is loaded in, as is (in-order). Also, it does not matter if all objects have the `children` property.

(I have tried to format it for easier reading)

```
newDataSet = [
    {"ID":0, "Value":10, "HIERARCHY_LEVEL":1, "children":[
        {"ID":1, "Value":20, "HIERARCHY_LEVEL":2, "children":[
            {"ID":2, "Value":55, "HIERARCHY_LEVEL":3}
        ]},
        {"ID":3, "Value":77, "HIERARCHY_LEVEL":2, "children":[
            {"ID":4, "Value":29, "HIERARCHY_LEVEL":3, "children":[
                {"ID":5, "Value":44, "HIERARCHY_LEVEL":4, "children":[
                    {"ID":6, "Value":34, "HIERARCHY_LEVEL":5}
                ]},
                {"ID":7, "Value":56, "HIERARCHY_LEVEL":4}
            ]}
        ]},
        {"ID":8, "Value":23, "HIERARCHY_LEVEL":2, "children":[
            {"ID":9, "Value":23, "HIERARCHY_LEVEL":3}
        ]}
    ]},
    {"ID":10, "Value":23, "HIERARCHY_LEVEL":1, "children":[
        {"ID":11, "Value":23, "HIERARCHY_LEVEL":2},
        {"ID":12, "Value":23, "HIERARCHY_LEVEL":2, "children":[
            {"ID":13, "Value":23, "HIERARCHY_LEVEL":3}
        ]}
    ]}
]
```

## Edit

### My current code

```
let newResults = [];
let topHierarchyLevel = 1;
let resultCounter = (newResults.length - 1); //Get the 2nd last element of newResults
let currentLevel = 2;
let loopCounter = 0;
for (loopCounter; loopCounter < dataSet.rows.length; loopCounter++) {
    let row = dataSet.rows[loopCounter];
    row["children"] = [];
    if (row.HIERARCHY_LEVEL == topHierarchyLevel) {
        newResults.push(row);
        resultCounter++;
    } else {
        if (row.HIERARCHY_LEVEL == 2) {
            newResults[resultCounter].children.push(row);
            currentLevel++;
        } else if (row.HIERARCHY_LEVEL > 2) {
            newResults[resultCounter-1].children.children.push(row);
            currentLevel++;
            resultCounter++;
        } else {
            currentLevel--;
            resultCounter--;
            loopCounter--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ...do you have a question? SO isn't a code-writing service.

Comment: @jonrsharpe How would you iterate through each level and add it to it's corresponding hierarchy level?

Comment: And which part of that exactly are you stuck on? Do you know how to iterate over the array, for example? If not, an introductory tutorial would be more appropriate than an SO question. Please give a [mcve] showing what you've tried and where precisely you've got to.

Comment: Yes i'm able to iterate over the array and find which hierarchy i'm currently on. However, i'm not able to add the row to the nested `children` property as the levels go on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the level property `HIERARCHY_LEVEL` for indicating the nested position in a helper array.

Then iterate the data and build children arrays, if necessary.

```js
function getTree(array) {
    var levels = [{}];
    array.forEach(function (o) {
        levels.length = o.HIERARCHY_LEVEL;
        levels[o.HIERARCHY_LEVEL - 1].children = levels[o.HIERARCHY_LEVEL - 1].children || [];
        levels[o.HIERARCHY_LEVEL - 1].children.push(o);
        levels[o.HIERARCHY_LEVEL] = o;
    });
    return levels[0].children;
}

var data = [{ ID: 0, Value: 10, HIERARCHY_LEVEL: 1 }, { ID: 1, Value: 20, HIERARCHY_LEVEL: 2 }, { ID: 2, Value: 55, HIERARCHY_LEVEL: 3 }, { ID: 3, Value: 77, HIERARCHY_LEVEL: 2 }, { ID: 4, Value: 29, HIERARCHY_LEVEL: 3 }, { ID: 5, Value: 44, HIERARCHY_LEVEL: 4 }, { ID: 6, Value: 34, HIERARCHY_LEVEL: 5 }, { ID: 7, Value: 56, HIERARCHY_LEVEL: 4 }, { ID: 8, Value: 23, HIERARCHY_LEVEL: 2 }, { ID: 9, Value: 23, HIERARCHY_LEVEL: 3 }, { ID: 10, Value: 23, HIERARCHY_LEVEL: 1 }, { ID: 11, Value: 23, HIERARCHY_LEVEL: 2 }, { ID: 12, Value: 23, HIERARCHY_LEVEL: 2 }, { ID: 13, Value: 23, HIERARCHY_LEVEL: 3 }];

console.log(getTree(data));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Question: Why is the parameter `level` passed though on the `getTree` function as I believe it's not being used? Also, when I try to run this, I get the error **Property `children` does not exist on type '`{}`'**, do you know why?

Comment: the parameter was leftover of a try to use a variable for the key of level. the other problem shoud not occur with levels starting with one and all levels have no holes, like level 5 follows after level 3, without level 4.